# ¿Como crear un Objeto con referencia a otros en una Base de Datos con Spring JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

me dirijo a ustedes con la siguiente consulta:
Tengo entidades cuya relacion es -> Personajes @ManyToMany Peliculas , Peliculas @ManyToOne Genero.
El problema es el siguiente, creo un objeto Personaje con una lista de Peliculas, lo guardo en la bd, y luego quiero instanciar otro personaje con la misma lista de Peliculas, pero me lanza un error-

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: app.disney.entitys.MovieOrSerie;

Por lo que he leido es un problema de persistencia, ya que al querer instanciar el 2do Objeto con la misma lista no me deja al estar estos otros objetos ya en la Base de Datos.
Como podria solucionar esto de una manera facil sin utilizar EntityManagment?
Dejo el codigo  que falla, el contexto es de prueba :

```
    // carga de base de pruebas
@BeforeAll
void seendDb() {
    Gender gen1 = new Gender("dibujo");
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.of(2003, 6, 20);
    MovieOrSerie mov1 = new MovieOrSerie("la Bella y la Bestia", date1, 3, gen1);

    Gender gen2 = new Gender("dibujo");
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.of(2008, 5, 4);
    MovieOrSerie mov2 = new MovieOrSerie("la Bella y la Bestia 2", date2, 4, gen2);

    List<MovieOrSerie> listMos = new ArrayList<>();
    listMos.add(mov1);
    listMos.add(mov2);
    

    

    Personage bestia = new Personage("bestia", 35, 120.0, listMos);
    personajeRepo.save(bestia);

    Personage bella = new Personage("Bella", 25, 60.0, listMos );
    personajeRepo.save(bella);
    

}
```

**Relacion Personaje - Peliculas**

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE , CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinTable(name = "personage_mos", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "personage_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mos_id"))
private List<MovieOrSerie> listMOS;
```

**Relacion Peliculas - Genero**

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST})
@JoinColumn
private Gender gender;
```

Comment: *save* es un método propio de Hibernate y no es parte de JPA; yo usaría *persist* que funciona de forma diferente. Por ejemplo, las instancias pasadas a *save* siguen en estado *detached* (como si no estuvieran vinculadas a la BD).